# Find Matching rows of recipes that only contains given ingredients

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables in MySql `RECIPES`,`INGREDIENTS` and `RECIPE_INGREDIENTS`. Now I want to fetch recipes that contains only ingredients ids supplied. I simple language I want to search recipes that I can make from ingredients I have.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query in order to get the ids of the recipes having all, or some, of the specified ingredients:

```
SELECT r.id
FROM Recipes AS r
INNER JOIN Recipe_ingredients AS ri ON r.id = ri.recipe_id
INNER JOIN Ingredients AS i ON i.id = ri.ingredient_id
WHERE i.id IN ( ... list of ids here ...)
GROUP BY r.id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT i.id) <= n -- where n is the number of the ingredient ids
                                 -- specified in the list of the where clause
```

**Edit:** If you want to get recipes that don't contain any ingredient that is not contained in the specified list, then you can use:

```
SELECT r.id
FROM Recipes AS r
LEFT JOIN Recipe_ingredients AS ri ON r.id = ri.recipe_id
LEFT JOIN Ingredients AS i ON i.id = ri.ingredient_id
WHERE i.id NOT IN ( ... list of ids here ...)
GROUP BY r.id
HAVING COUNT(i.id) = 0
```

Comment: This will show recipes that include all of the existing ingredients - but that's subtly different from what was actually asked for. An exclusion join is actually what's required in this instance - all the recipes that don't include ingredients I don't have.

Comment: @Strawberry I think my query returns recipes that include *only* all of the *specified* ingredient ids.

Comment: I think you're mistaken - and besides, that's *still* not what's wanted!

Comment: @Giorgos Betsos That's not what was asked for. If you have milk, sugar and flour. You should also return recipes that only require milk and flour, because you can also make that from your ingredients.

Comment: @Strawberry Just look at the `HAVING` clause. It guarantees that *only* `r.id` values having *all* of the ids specified in the list are returned.

Comment: @jussius Ok, now I see the point. Perhaps I have misunderstood the intentions of the OP. But the query can easily be adjusted: `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT i.id) <= n`

Comment: GB - Better - but I guess I'm still not quite getting the point across. If you're interested, see my link above.

Comment: @Strawberry Please check the edit I made.

Comment: Does that work with my data set?